# How to set background color of cell with NSButtoncell type in NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstableview, nscell

This is my table view delegate:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row
{
    id theRecord;
    NSMutableString *gid;

    theRecord = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    gid = [theRecord objectForKey:@"gid"];

    if (([gid intValue] % 2) != 0)
    {
        [aCell setDrawsBackground: YES];
        [aCell setBackgroundColor: [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed: 237.0 / 255.0
                                                             green: 243.0 / 255.0
                                                              blue: 254.0 / 255.0
                                                             alpha: 1.0]];

    }
    else
    {
        [aCell setDrawsBackground: NO];
    }
}
```

It works fine to display normal cell but the tableview get frozen after I add a cell with  NSButtonCell type (for checkbox). How to fix it ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [NSButtonCell reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can only specify a background color for borderless buttons. Have you tried to use borderless button cells ?

Moreover, I cannot find `setDrawsBackground:` method for [NSButtonCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html); I can only find it for [NSTextFieldCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Have you tried to remove the call ?

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to Cocoa. Need to read documentation more often. Thanks!